# How to add two decimal zeroes while exporting a dataframe as an excel and add percentage on only values not dash

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyexcel

I have a Dataframe like

```
A%  B %
2   3
-   2.1
100 0
-   5
```

i want the output exported excel to be like

```
A%        B%
2.00%     3.00%
-         2.10%
100.00%   0.00%
-         5.00%
```

I have these A% and B% by using the following logic

```
((df['some_values1'] / df['some_values2']) *100.00).round(2).astype(str)+('%')
```

but **when i make the excel of the df the - get converted to nan and the single digits like 2, 100, 0 does not have two decimals like 2.00% 100.00% & 0.00% it is 2%,100% and 0%** only whereas it works fine with 2.1 and other fractional digits.

### Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that suits your needs:

```
def to_percent_format(p):
    if str(p).strip() != "-":
        return "{:.2%}".format(p/100)
    else:
        return p.strip()
```

Indeed:

```
>>> to_percent_format(3)
'3.00%'
>>> to_percent_format("-")
'-'
```

And just apply it to your dataframe!

```
df.apply(to_percent_format, axis=1)
```

Comment: It worked but - are getting converted to nan in output any suggestions ?

Comment: its still giving a nan% to - values

Comment: Try using `p.strip()` (in case some of your values are in fact `"- "` or `" - "`). Updated my function.

Comment: This is what i an using
 df['sample1 %']=((df['sample2'] / df['sample3']) *100.00).astype(str).apply(lambda p: "{:.2%}".format(p/100) if p.strip() != "-" else p.strip())

it giving still giving error like  unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
i have used float to it is now working. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Yes. You use `.astype(str)` so your inputs are now strings. Therefore asking for `.format(p/100)` doesn't work, as `p` is of type `str` and not `int` anymore. Try using `.format(int(p)/100)` instead.

Comment: Its not working for "-" its still throwing Nan% can you suggest a apply method i can apply on specific columns to replace nan% with - ?